# Are there any Java based Graphql client to invoke graphql server from java code?

Tags: java, graphql, graphql-java, github-graphql, apollo-android

My application (spring-boot application) is going to invoke a set of graphQL services hosted in different server. My java code (server side) needs to invoke those services to fetch & update data.

I'm looking for Java based GraphQL clients (API) so that I can invoke those services from my server side java code.

I know apollo-android graphQL client is used to builds Android Apps, but I'm not sure whether the same API will work here as well or not.

Please help me here.

Comment: Thanks Mark Rotteveel, CommonsWare.

As a client system developer, I want to download the GraphQL schema from server while building (using Gradle) my project. As per ApolloGraphQL guide (https://www.apollographql.com/docs/ios/downloading-schema.html), we can download the schema using Apollo-codegen by Node.js. I'm not using Node.js in my project and I'm not allowed to use this.  Could you please help me - how I can download the schema from server every time I build my project using Gradle.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/Shopify/graphql_java_gen as well. It can generate a client for many platforms.

Comment: There are two major GraphQL clients available at the moment. The first one is Apollo Client, which is a community-driven effort to build a powerful and flexible GraphQL client for all major development platforms. The second one is called Relay and it is Facebook’s homegrown GraphQL client that heavily optimizes for performance and is only available on the web.
https://www.apollographql.com/client/
https://facebook.github.io/relay/